# azure-mysql instance connection from GAE

Tags: java, mysql, azure, google-app-engine

can i connect to azure MySQL instance from Google App Engine?

```
<properties>
 <!--   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />   -->
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="azure-my-sql@azure-my-sql" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root@123" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Yes, but to do it you want to give a try to Google Socket API, not sure if it will work or not

Comment: Thanks..It worked

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Socket API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/) is the solution to your question